# How to create isometry imitation in 2d Racing game?

Tags: flash, 2d, actionscript-3, isometric

How can I modify 2d racing game to seem like isometry? Flash + ActionScript3

[ScreeShot](http://s52.radikal.ru/i137/1007/e9/7db324ec9083.jpg)

The game is totally in 2d. Car moves like it should and while it drives the ground everything is fine. 
I've added a grey ramp. Now the car should move like the arrows are showing, creating illusion of a 3d (isometry).

Ramp is divided in 3 sectors

-first,sector to the right (where the car is currently situated);

-second,sector to the left;

-third, sector on top;

Plus I need the car,to jump out from the ramp when the speed is high. I reffer to old scholl game Rock'n'Roll Racing (Blizzard's game for Sega)

So the questions are

1) **How should I change car's angle and velocities**(velocityX and velocityY) **when driving on the ramp ?**

2) **How can I initiate jumping out of the ramp? For example like in Rock'n'Roll racing? or how Blizzards essentially did it?** (maybe suggestions)

Thaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best is to calculate the game in 3D and then simply project it into isometry.

```
const angle:Number = Math.PI/3;//you may want to tweak this one
const xVec:Point = Point.polar(-Math.PI/2 + angle, 1);
const yVec:Point = Point.polar(-Math.PI/2 - angle, 1);
const zVec:Point = new Point(0, -1);
```

transform 3D to 2D:

```
function transform(x:Number, y:Number, z:Number):Point {
     return new Point(x*xVec.x + y*yVec.x + z*zVec.x, x*xVec.y + y*yVec.y + z*zVec.y);
}
```